# QT Console and spyder in Anaconda 4.8.2 with Python 3.8.x raised NotImplementedError from asyncio\events.py

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, python-3.8

I have created a new environment in Anaconda (Windows X) with the AnacondaNavigator. The environment is called py3_8_20200407 and has **Python 3.8.x** and **Spyder 4.x**. When I start Spyder, the newly opened Spyder window freezes after a while and gets unresponsive. If I try with the QT Console instead I get the same error as below: (output shown is from `spyder --debug-info verbose`)

```
2020-04-07 16:56:19,075 [INFO] [spyder.app.mainwindow] -> Deleting previous Spyder instance LSP logs...
2020-04-07 16:56:19,127 [DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Using default logger
2020-04-07 16:56:19,239 [INFO] [spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.utils.kernelspec] -> Kernel command: ['C:\\Users\\me\\.conda\\envs\\py3_8_20200407\\python.exe', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', '{connection_file}']
2020-04-07 16:56:19,240 [DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Starting kernel: ['C:\\Users\\me\\.conda\\envs\\py3_8_20200407\\python.exe', '-m', 'spyder_kernels.console', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-3964ff42f733.json']
2020-04-07 16:56:19,249 [DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57565
2020-04-07 16:56:19,258 [DEBUG] [traitlets] -> connecting heartbeat channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:57566
2020-04-07 16:56:19,261 [DEBUG] [asyncio] -> Using proactor: IocpProactor
2020-04-07 16:56:19,262 [DEBUG] [asyncio] -> Using proactor: IocpProactor
2020-04-07 16:56:19,263 [DEBUG] [traitlets] -> connecting shell channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:57562
2020-04-07 16:56:19,263 [DEBUG] [traitlets] -> Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57562
2020-04-07 16:56:19,270 [ERROR] [tornado.application] -> Exception in callback functools.partial(<function ThreadedZMQSocketChannel.__init__.<locals>.setup_stream at 0x0000024B9D406E50>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py3_8_20200407\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py3_8_20200407\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\threaded.py", line 47, in setup_stream
    self.stream = zmqstream.ZMQStream(self.socket, self.ioloop)
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py3_8_20200407\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 127, in __init__
    self._init_io_state()
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py3_8_20200407\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 546, in _init_io_state
    self.io_loop.add_handler(self.socket, self._handle_events, self.io_loop.READ)
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py3_8_20200407\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 100, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py3_8_20200407\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

I have tired workarounds suggested in other threads. But the asincio.py contains already

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32' and hasattr(asyncio, "WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy"):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

I have tried different versions of Python and only versions <= 3.7.7 work with Spyder 4.1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Neither QtConsole nor Spyder can work at the moment (April 2020) with Python 3.8. However, we'll try to release new versions at the end of the month that will fix the problem you posted above.